# failing to use rootscope in directive "Cant read property $emit of undefined"

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code am getting the error "Cant read property $emit of undefined" where have i gone wrong?

```
.directive('managesubcategorybusinesses',function()
 {
    return function(scope,element,attrs,$rootScope)
    {
        element.bind("click",function()
        {
            scope.getBusinesses(attrs.subcategoryid,function(data)
            {

                $rootScope.$emit("CallSubcategoryBusinesses",{data : data});
                console.log("tadaa");
            })


        });

    };
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use scope instead of $rootscope

```
scope.$emit
```